# http and https with 2 different domains in a single nginx server

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx in my aws server and hosting 2 ruby on rails apps there. HTTPS is enable in one of my server (example.com is below example file) and other server is on HTTP (test.com).

Now the problem which I am facing is https://test.com is able to access example.com (which should not happen). test.com is configured for port 80 and it is also able to access port 443.

Here is my nginx configuration file :

```
upstream example {
  server unix:///tmp/example.sock;
}

upstream test {
  server unix:///tmp/test.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com; # change to match your URL
  return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 default;
  server_name example.com;

  root /home/deploy/example/current/public;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 15M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_pass http://example; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name test.com www.test.com blog.test.com; # change to match your URL
  root /home/deploy/test/current/public; # I assume your app is located at this location

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://test; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }


  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need two IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one IP address, you can redirect https://test.com to http://test.com with a new `server` section like this:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         test.com www.test.com blog.test.com;
    ssl_certificate     example_or_test.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key example_or_test.com.key;
    return         301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution will issue warnings in browsers if you do not have a valid certificat for test.com or if you use the example.com certificat.

**Old reply**

You can use:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
    ...
}
```

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server

If you have only one IP, NGinx support SNI.

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni

Comment: Tried but didn't worked for me. I can still access "https://test.com":https://test.com

Comment: You want "test.com" to be http only ?

Comment: Yes, test.com should be http and example.com should be https

Comment: Okay, see my updated reply.

Comment: That worked, though its not a clean solution.I was think to implement something similar but at the application level. Thanks a lot !